# Why is it "an FFP2 mask"?

Tags: grammar, indefinite-articles

The indefinite article "a" is changed to "an" if the following word starts with a vowel or and silent "h".
Now I read "an FFP2 mask" everywhere. Is this correct, and if so, why?

Comment: Because the letter F is pronounced _eff_, so it is treated like a word beginning with a vowel.

Comment: The a/an issue is 99.9% controlled by the sound when the next item is read out aloud by a proficient reader. So some write 'an NP' while others who treat the abbreviation as a purely orthographic device write 'a NP' because they expand on reading aloud to 'a noun phrase'. But few would expand 'an FAQ' or 'a UGV' on reading out the initialism. // And _acronyms_ are pronounced as words: 'a UNESCO ruling'.

Comment: Very succinct, @EdwinAshworth. A good example of an acronym starting with a consonent would be the Federation Against Software Theft or FAST. One would refer to _a_ FAST initiative since the acronym is pronounced as a word but if the acronym was not well established one might refer to it as _an_ eff, ay, ess, tee initiative if the acronym were to be spread out like that.

Comment: @BoldBen The default definition of 'acronym' (check all the usual online dictionaries; there may be one not in agreement) mandates the 'pronounced as a word' (whether now lower-cased like 'radar', or not, like 'FAST') requirement. This has been covered on ELU. 'Initialisms' is the term for those _abbreviations consisting of some or all especially salient initial/near-initial letters of the expanded form ... which are 'spelled out'_.